# How do I properly free memory related to getline() function?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, getline

I just started programming and have a beginner question, I want to write a function to read a file with unknown length line by line. Since I wouldn't know the length of each line so I used `getline()` function:

```
void readDict(FILE *dict_file){
  //Read dic 
  char *line;
  size_t len = 0, read;
  while((read = getline(&line, &len, dict_file))!=-1){
    check(line); 
  }
  free(line);
  return;
}
```

Since `getline()` is kind of similar to `malloc()` and `realloc()` a string, so if I keep using this function to read a lot of line with unknown length, would I get a memory leak or out of memory?

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html), you need to `malloc` memory for `line` _before_ calling `getline`.

Comment: @bejado Nope, it's not a must.

Comment: @SouravGhosh how would you do it without allocating memory?

Comment: @bejado _"If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program."_

Comment: @SouravGhosh didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First of all, you should initialize `lineptr` to `NULL`. Without a proper initialization, `lineptr` will contain indeterminate value, which makes `lineptr` to point to invalid memory location and later in process, it will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) while trying to allocate (`realloc()`) appropriate amount of memory.

Then, as per the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline),

> [...] before calling `getline()`, `*lineptr` can contain a pointer to a `malloc()`-allocated buffer `*n` bytes in size. If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, `getline()` resizes it with `realloc()`, updating `*lineptr` and `*n` as necessary.

So, as long as you pass the same `*lineptr`, you should be OK if you `free()` only once in the end.

Comment: So when I initialize the pointer it should be {char *line=NULL;}  ?

Comment: @GhostKidYao Yep.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your answer!